# probability of 1s next to each other in sequence of numbers

Tags: probability

I have a sequence of binary numbers (zeros and ones) and I'm trying to find the probability that $2$ ones will be next to each other.

For example, I have something like: $11000$. So if I have two $1s$ I can distribute them in  ${5 \choose 2}$ =10 combinations? And then the number of ways that they can be next to each other equals 4 (11000,01100, 00110, 00011)? So the probability is $4/10$=$40$%?
Is my solution correct?

Comment: "So I have a sequence of binary numbers (zeros and ones)" - how many do you have in total? BTW, in your example there are a lot more than $2$ (out of $16$) combinations where two ones are next to each other.

Comment: Where did the $n$ and the $k$ in $(n-k+1)=2$ come from, and what are they equal to?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! sequence of binary numbers comes from the experiment and zeros and ones are the sleep status of fruit flies... i'm trying to find if there is any correlation of sleep between the adjacent flies (one fly fall asleep - next one sleeps as well) or not... atm I have sequence of 20 binary numbers... N is number of numbers in sequence (4 in the example) and k=number of 1s in sequence (3 in example)... I suspect that my solution might not be correct... anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The probability you've computed only accounts for the event that exactly two 1s show up sequentially, but not for strings like $10110$.

Comment: @Ellie, sorry for not looking at this question again earlier.  Your comment and edit help, but it's still a bit unclear what probability you're asking for.  It might help if you added a second example, with $n=6$ and $k=3$, e.g., $110100$, etc.  The sample space there has only ${6\choose3}=20$ combinations, but what is the event you want?

Comment: ok so if i have 5 numbers and want to find out how many pairs of 1s next to each other I can get, how do I do that? for example, I have 3 ones, so I can get 11100, 01110, 00111, 11010, 11001, 01101, 10110, 1001, 01011 which in total gives me 12 pairs... for 2 ones out of 5 I get 4 pairs... but what is the correct formula to calculate it?

Comment: @Ellie, it sounds like what you're asking for is the *expected number* of consecutive $1$'s in a binary string of length $n$ with $k$ $1$'s.  (In the example $n=5$, $k=3$ in your last comment, the expected number is $12/10=1.2$.)  If that's actually what you want, you should edit your question accordingly.  It's still unclear what you mean by "the probability that two $1$'s will be next to each other."  The problem is, there are a couple of different ways to interpret that.